# For what values of c is ||c(1,2,3)|| = 1?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I just wanted to check if what I'm doing for a particular problem is correct. My background: business student with average math skills taking a linear algebra class. Would appreciate it if someone confirms what I'm doing and/or points me to the right direction!

**Question:** For what values of $c$ is $||c(1,2,3)|| = 1?$

Here's what I have so far:

$$||(c,2c,3c)|| = 1$$
$$\sqrt{(c)^{2}+(2c)^{2}+(3c)^{2}} = 1$$
$$\sqrt{c^{2}+4c^{2}+9c^{2}} = 1$$
$$\sqrt{14c^{2}} = 1$$
$$\sqrt{14}\cdot c = 1$$
$$c = \sqrt{\frac{1}{14}}$$

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful
$$\forall x \in \mathbf{R}, \sqrt{x^2} = |x|$$
In general, $|x| \neq x$.

Here you have
$$
|c| = \sqrt{\frac{1}{14}}
$$
so
$$
c = \sqrt{\frac{1}{14}} \text{ or } c = -\sqrt{\frac{1}{14}}
$$

Comment: Totally forgot about this. Thanks so much!